# d3.js How to make all the nodes collapsed in Collapsible indented Tree

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to work on a sample d3 collapsible tree. mbostock’s block #1093025. Initially when the form is loaded, how do i make all the nodes collapsed initially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a function for that in your json loading.
Check that example : http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

Answer (score 4):

The way the nodes are collapsed in this example is by removing the `.children` member of the data elements such that no children are drawn. You can do this statically to have everything collapsed to start with. The code would look like this.

```
function moveChildren(node) {
    if(node.children) {
        node.children.forEach(function(c) { moveChildren(c); });
        node._children = node.children;
        node.children = null;
    }
}
moveChildren(json);
```

Modified example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/7022289).