# On Loading D3 Tree Layout chart all nodes should be collapsed under root node

Tags: charts, d3.js

I'm using the following chart from D3 Gallery, I want all the node in this chart to collapsed under one node while loading first time,

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [d3.js How to make all the nodes collapsed in Collapsible indented Tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423396/d3-js-how-to-make-all-the-nodes-collapsed-in-collapsible-indented-tree)

Comment: Thanks this is behavior i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Just manually *click* it after drawing it for the first time:

```js
d3.json("flare.json", function(json) {
  json.x0 = 0;
  json.y0 = 0;
  update(root = json);
  click(root);
});
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://bl.ocks.org/musically-ut/7523521)

However, do note that it becomes much less *discoverable* in this case.